# selenium phpunit click function not working

Tags: selenium, phpunit

I am using friefox 27.0.1 and selenium stand alone 2.15 i am getting below error for click()

RuntimeException: Invalid response while accessing the Selenium Server at : ERROR: Command execution failure. Please search the user group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users for error details from the log window.  The error message is: Argument 1 of EventTarget.dispatchEvent does not implement interface Event.

Comment: try updating selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updates selenium to 2.39.0 and firefox version to 28 then it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are extremely out of date.  Upgrade to the selenium standalone of `2.40.0` and this will fix your issue.

Source:

Person that had experience with this exact issue.